# WPF - Trigger "LostFocus" on currently active element in Tab before Tab Change

Tags: c#, wpf, events, tabs, lost-focus

I have a TabControl, and each TabItem has multiple, data-bound textboxes. When I edit an text in one box, and the switch the tab directly (without leaving the textbox), the change is lost. Apparently, the "LostFocus" Event is not triggered when changing the tab, so the new value is not written to the bound property.

How can I trigger the "LostFocus" on the currently active (or all) elements in the active tab before changing over to the new tab?

I could surely do an override and call the event manually on all elements, but that would be quite unhandy because one has to update that list every time a field is added.

Is there some way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` instead of `LostFocus` and set the binding `Delay` property to an interval of your choice.

Comment: I had hoped there was a more elegant way... Ok, but it sure works. Just have to remember to add it in XAML to every field. Thanks!

Comment: Really, there's multiple ways to go about this, depends what you're willing to implement or not. For example, you could create a control that inherits from TextBox and try to manipulate other available events/aspects of the control in an attempt to signal changes. I just answered with an out of the box solution which doesn't require more than changing binding properties.